# asp.net mvc3, how to make data annotations validation optional?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a review form.  it has 4 fields, title, category, link, and review

if category is a website, then link is required. if it is a book, link is optional, not required.  how do I validate the link field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx) which illustrates some custom validators such as `RequiredIf` that allow you to achieve this conditional validation.

Or if you are like me and prefer imperative validation logic rather than declarative simply use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which makes this validation scenario pretty trivial.

Comment: The first URL is now showing a 403 error response.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Mvc.ValidationTookit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx).

It has Conditional required validations

Comment: This is now showing a 403 error.